# TeamCity, MSBuild сломался

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

У нас было настроено CI на сервере. Все работало но в один момент проект перестал собираться.

Ошибка:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4276,
>   5): Web deployment task failed. (Attempted to perform an unauthorized
>   operation.)

В Файле Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets на строке 4276 находится это:

```
<VSMSDeploy
      Condition="!$(UseMsdeployExe)"
      MSDeployVersionsToTry="$(_MSDeployVersionsToTry)"
      Source="@(MsDeploySourceProviderSetting)"
      Destination="@(MsDeployDestinationProviderSetting)"
      DisableLink="$(PublishDisableLinks)"
      EnableLink="$(PublishEnableLinks)"
      AllowUntrustedCertificate="$(AllowUntrustedCertificate)"
      BuildingInsideVisualStudio="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)"
      SkipExtraFilesOnServer="$(SkipExtraFilesOnServer)"
      SkipRuleItems="@(MsDeploySkipRules)"
      SetParameterItems="@(_VsPublish_MsDeployDeclareParameters)"
      OptimisticParameterDefaultValue="$(EnableOptimisticParameterDefaultValue)"
      ImportSetParametersItems="$(_VsPublishParametersFile)"
      WhatIf="$(FilePreview)"
      RetryAttempts="$(RetryAttemptsForDeployment)"
      EnableMSDeployBackup="$(EnableMSDeployBackup)"
      EnableMSDeployAppOffline="$(EnableMSDeployAppOffline)"
      EnableMSDeployWebConfigEncryptRule="$(MSDeployEnableWebConfigEncryptRule)"
      AdditionalDestinationProviderOptions="@(MsDeployAdditionalDestinationProviderSettings)"
      UseChecksum="$(MSDeployUseChecksum)"
      UserAgent="$(_MSDeployUserAgent)"
      InvokedByPublish="true"
    >
```

В логах такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройки MSBuild:

```
MSBuild version: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5
MSBuild ToolsVersion:4.0

Command line parameters: 

/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0  
/p:Configuration=Debug 
/p:EnableRemoteDebugger=true 
/p:DeployOnBuild=True 
/p:PublishProfile="Deploy" 
/p:ProfileTransformWebConfigEnabled=False
```

Comment: Если еще актульно -Скорее всего у пользователя, под которым работает агент, не хватает прав. Смотрите логи на сторон сервера, на который деплоите:  http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy

Comment: "Все работало но в один момент проект перестал собираться." - все работало до момента когда я захотела добавить туда 2й сайт)))))
вобщем в моем случае проблема была с агентом. Было 2 сайта и 2 агента и один из агентов пытался запускать 2 сайта. Как-то так. Деталей уже не расскажу - давно это было

Comment: может быть стоит удалить вопрос, раз шаги все равно неизвестны?

Comment: почему же неизвестны - читать логи!! (как Nicolas подметил), там все написано.

Если хочешь, можешь удалить вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понял где Николас такое подметил, но в логах в вопросе написано "проект не собрался из-за нехватки прав". Проблема была в нехватке прав? :) я просто не могу понять не только как проблема воспроизвелась, но и как починилась.

Comment: Проблема была в том что у меня агнет неправильно был настроен, из-за чего он не мог собрать билд. И об этом я прочитала в логах.

А Николас посоветовал: "Смотрите логи на сторон сервера, на который деплоите"

Comment: это был я, а не Николас :) но вообще пожелание почитать логи подразумевает что топикастер запостит их как часть вопроса. в любом случае - проблема решена, так что все ок